# Sending notification on ticket creation

Tags: servicenow

I have an incident form with the fields `Opened by` and `Opened for`. A user can create a ticket for themselves (`Opened by == Opened for`) or create a ticket for another user (`Opened by != Opened for`). I would like to send out notifications when a ticket created. There are 2 scenarios:

Scenario 1: `Opened by == Opened for`

- Send to `Opened for` (e.g. You have created a ticket ...)

Scenario 2: `Opened by != Opened for`

- Send to `Opened for` (e.g. A ticket has been created for you by ...)
- Send to `Opened by` (e.g. You have created a ticket for ...)

I have created 3 notifications for this.

Question: Is it possible to do this using Flows? When I try to set this up using Flows with the. trigger being "Record created", I am not able to select the notification at all. Is there another way I can accomplish this?

See screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: The notification you've set up is almost 100% likely not referencing "x_1120536_ticket_1_ticket" table, which is why you're not seeing it in that drop-down

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you haven't created any notification for that table in the Notifications table.

After you create notifications, there are three ways to go in my opinion:

1. You can select in the notification record when to send (When record is updated or inserted) and specify conditions.
2. Send notification when an event is fired (later, the event you can be used in flows, in business rules, scheduled scripts, etc).
3. Don't specify any conditions or who will receive and use the notifications in the flow.

However, I would go with the first option, because that would require less effort and would be easier to manage, than going back to the flows and changing anything if there is a need.

Source for setting up notifications: https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/vancouver-platform-administration/page/administer/notification/concept/system-notifications.html